# Sqlite Server Version Different

Tags: python, sqlite

I have installed the SQLite database.Its version is 3.8.2.But when I am running the Python Script the version comes out to be 3.6.21.My Python code is:

```
#!/Python27/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sqlite3 as lite
import sys

con = None

try:
    con = lite.connect('test.db')

    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT SQLITE_VERSION()')

    data = cur.fetchone()

    print "SQLite version: %s" % data

except lite.Error, e:

    print "Error %s:" % e.args[0]
    sys.exit(1)

finally:

    if con:
        con.close()
```

As such there's no error with my code.

Comment: How did you create this database? If you create it in the same script and run the same SQL query from your `sqlite` command line tool, will it produce different version then? or is it limited to when you create it via command-line and then do the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite is an *embedded* database; there is no server.

Python uses its own copy of the SQLite library.
To upgrade that, you must upgrade Python, or compile your own Python version.